# SQL: Grouping across multiple table joins with a range, returning counts including 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count, group-by

Ok, so this is a pretty complex query (for me at least), involving data across four tables, Common Table Expressions, Joins, Grouping, and Ordering.

Basically, I am looking to count total users' answers within a range.

example tables:

**Cutrange** *list of UserIDs and the Range they fall in*

```
uID  | Range
-------------
1033 | 2
1033 | 4
1140 | 1
1140 | 4
1145 | 2
1145 | 4
1146 | 3
1146 | 4
1234 | 2
1234 | 4
...
```

**Answers** *collects response values for each question for each user*

```
QuesID | Value | ScaleID | uID
---------------------------------
 8     | 2     | 10      | 1033
 179   | 1     | 159     | 1033
 180   | 1     | 175     | 1033
 8     | 4     | 12      | 1146
 179   | 1     | 159     | 1146
 180   | 1     | 175     | 1146     
 8     | 2     | 10      | 1234
 179   | 2     | 160     | 1234
 180   | 2     | 178     | 1234
 ...
```

**Scales** *defines answer range for each question*

```
QuesID | Value | ScaleID
------------------------
179    | 1     | 159
179    | 2     | 160
180    | 0     | 174
180    | 1     | 175 
180    | 2     | 176
180    | 3     | 177
180    | 4     | 178
180    | 5     | 179
...
```

**RangeDef** *defines a range by which to group data*

```
CutID | Range | RangeDef
-------------------------
1     | 1     | 0-1
1     | 2     | 2-3
1     | 3     | 4-5
1     | 4     | All
```

I am joining the above tables (actually Common Table Expressions that are a result of other joins) to give a report of the count of the UserIDs across each Question by each possible answer Value across a Range grouping.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
COUNT(Cutrange.uID) AS ttl, 
Cutrange.Range
FROM Cutrange 
JOIN Answers ON Cutrange.uID = Answers.uID 
RIGHT JOIN Scales ON Answers.ScaleID = Scales.ScaleID
GROUP BY Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
Cutrange.Range 
ORDER BY Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
Cutrange.Range
```

Which returns:

```
QuesID | Value | ScaleID | ttl | Range
---------------------------------------
179    | 1     | 159     | 16  | 1
179    | 1     | 159     | 1   | 2
179    | 1     | 159     | 17  | 4
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 1
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 2
179    | 2     | 160     | 2   | 4
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | NULL
180    | 1     | 175     | 5   | 1
180    | 1     | 175     | 1   | 2
180    | 1     | 175     | 6   | 4
180    | 2     | 176     | 12  | 1
180    | 2     | 176     | 1   | 2
180    | 2     | 176     | 13  | 4
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | NULL
180    | 4     | 178     | 0   | NULL
180    | 5     | 179     | 0   | NULL
```

*(Note the **ttl** reflects a larger set of data than just the few rows I included in the example table above)*

That is close, but it doesn't include the totals for all 4 items in the Range. This is because in this particular subset of the data, none of the users fall within Range 3. I want all the Ranges represented, with 0 values where appropriate. So I add a JOIN with the **RangeDef** table.

```
SELECT Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
COUNT(Cutrange.uID) AS ttl, 
RangeDef.Range
FROM Cutrange 
JOIN Answers ON Cutrange.uID = Answers.uID 
RIGHT JOIN Scales ON Answers.ScaleID = Scales.ScaleID, RangeDef
WHERE RangeDef.CutID = 1
GROUP BY Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
RangeDef.Range
ORDER BY Scales.QuesID, Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, RangeDef.Range
```

Which returns:

```
QuesID | Value | ScaleID | ttl | Range
---------------------------------------
179    | 1     | 159     | 34  | 1
179    | 1     | 159     | 34  | 2
179    | 1     | 159     | 34  | 3
179    | 1     | 159     | 34  | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 2     | 160     | 4   | 1
179    | 2     | 160     | 4   | 2
179    | 2     | 160     | 4   | 3
179    | 2     | 160     | 4   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 1
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 2
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 3
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 1     | 175     | 12  | 1
180    | 1     | 175     | 12  | 2
180    | 1     | 175     | 12  | 3
180    | 1     | 175     | 12  | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 2     | 176     | 26  | 1
180    | 2     | 176     | 26  | 2
180    | 2     | 176     | 26  | 3
180    | 2     | 176     | 26  | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 1
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 2
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 3
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 4
...
```

That gives me the correct groupings, but the **ttl** column is now off. This is because COUNT(Cutrange.uID) needs to be grouped by Cutrange.Range. Right now it is grouped by RangeDef.Range. I can't figure out how to group the **ttl** column by Range and also inlcude all 4 ranges.
When I change the GROUP BY statement to include Cutrange.Range, I get the following:

```
SELECT Scales.QuesID, 
       Scales.Value, 
       Scales.ScaleID, 
       COUNT(Cutrange.uID) AS ttl, 
       RangeDef.Range
FROM Cutrange 
JOIN Answers ON Cutrange.uID = Answers.uID 
RIGHT JOIN Scales ON Answers.ScaleID = Scales.ScaleID, RangeDef
WHERE RangeDef.CutID = 1
GROUP BY     Scales.QuesID, 
             Scales.Value, 
             Scales.ScaleID, 
             Cutrange.Range, 
             RangeDef.Range
ORDER BY  Scales.QuesID, 
          Scales.Value, 
          Scales.ScaleID, 
          RangeDef.Range




QuesID | Value | ScaleID | ttl | Range
---------------------------------------
179    | 1     | 159     | 16  | 1
179    | 1     | 159     | 1   | 1
179    | 1     | 159     | 17  | 1
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 1     | 159     | 16  | 2
179    | 1     | 159     | 1   | 2
179    | 1     | 159     | 17  | 2
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 1     | 159     | 16  | 3
179    | 1     | 159     | 1   | 3
179    | 1     | 159     | 17  | 3
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 1     | 159     | 16  | 4
179    | 1     | 159     | 1   | 4
179    | 1     | 159     | 17  | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 1
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 1
179    | 2     | 160     | 2   | 1
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 2
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 2
179    | 2     | 160     | 2   | 2
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 3
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 3
179    | 2     | 160     | 2   | 3
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 4
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 4
179    | 2     | 160     | 2   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 1
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 2
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 3
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 1     | 175     | 5   | 1
180    | 1     | 175     | 1   | 1
180    | 1     | 175     | 6   | 1
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 1     | 175     | 5   | 2
180    | 1     | 175     | 1   | 2
180    | 1     | 175     | 6   | 2
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 1     | 175     | 5   | 3
180    | 1     | 175     | 1   | 3
180    | 1     | 175     | 6   | 3
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 1     | 175     | 5   | 4
180    | 1     | 175     | 1   | 4
180    | 1     | 175     | 6   | 4
...
```

So that is incorrect and doesn't really give me anything I can work with.

Here is what I need:

```
QuesID | Value | ScaleID | ttl | Range
---------------------------------------
179    | 1     | 159     | 16  | 1
179    | 1     | 159     | 1   | 2
179    | 1     | 159     | 0   | 3
179    | 1     | 159     | 17  | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 1
179    | 2     | 160     | 1   | 2
179    | 2     | 160     | 0   | 3
179    | 2     | 160     | 2   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 1
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 2
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 3
180    | 0     | 174     | 0   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 1     | 175     | 5   | 1
180    | 1     | 175     | 1   | 2
180    | 1     | 175     | 0   | 3
180    | 1     | 175     | 6   | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 2     | 176     | 12  | 1
180    | 2     | 176     | 1   | 2
180    | 2     | 176     | 0   | 3
180    | 2     | 176     | 13  | 4
-------+-------+---------+-----+-------
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 1
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 2
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 3
180    | 3     | 177     | 0   | 4
...
```

I have tried playing around with GROUPING SETS, and adding an OVER(PARTITION BY) to the **ttl**, but none of that has worked yet. I have also tried the different JOIN types (CROSS, RIGHT OUTER) on the RangeDef table, but again, no luck.
I really though that

```
COUNT(Cutrange.uID) OVER(Partition By Cutrange.Range) AS ttl
```

was the answer, but SQL seems to require Cutrange.uID to be included in either an aggregate function (which I thought COUNT() was) or in the GROUP BY statement. I am not looking for a report by User, I am looking for a report by Question.

I have also tried including Range in the **Answers** table (JOIN on uID) in an effort to simplify the end query, but that still doesn't get me there. I still run into the problem with the COUNT groupings within the range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Hopefully the data above isn't too confusing, all the data has been filtered from a larger data set and, again, my source tables above are all CTEs. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you were already pretty darn close. I changed the RIGHT JOIN on Scales into a subselect that does a cartesian join on RangeDef. All this really does is add a range column onto the Scales table. Let me know if this fixes things for you.

```
SELECT s.QuesID, 
s.Value, 
s.ScaleID, 
COUNT(Cutrange.uID) AS ttl, 
s.Range
FROM Cutrange
JOIN Answers 
  ON Cutrange.uID = Answers.uID 
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT s.QuesID, s.Value, s.ScaleID, rd.range FROM Scales s, RangeDef rd WHERE rd.CutID = 1)  s
  ON Answers.ScaleID = s.ScaleID
 AND Cutrange.range = s.range
GROUP BY s.QuesID, 
s.Value, 
s.ScaleID, 
s.Range
ORDER BY s.QuesID, s.Value, 
s.ScaleID, s.Range;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bfe6/3) Note: I used MySQL to test this out, so I had to change range to range2 because of a reserved word. The option to use MS SQL Server 2014 is down right now.

Comment: That worked!!!! Thank you so much. This query has been driving me nuts for months (on and off) now. I keep coming back to it and not really getting anywhere, and it was slowing down progress elsewhere. I really appreciate your time an knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is you are doing a cartesian join on RangeDef which is why your counts get all out of wack when you added that table. I find the best way to build out a query is start with the table you always want the results of and flesh out the query from there. In this case you want to start with RangeDef.

```
SELECT Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
COUNT(Cutrange.uID) AS ttl, 
RangeDef.Range
FROM RangeDef
LEFT OUTER JOIN Cutrange
  ON RangeDef.Range = Cutrange.Range
JOIN Answers 
  ON Cutrange.uID = Answers.uID 
RIGHT JOIN Scales 
  ON Answers.ScaleID = Scales.ScaleID
WHERE RangeDef.CutID = 1
GROUP BY Scales.QuesID, 
Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, 
RangeDef.Range
ORDER BY Scales.QuesID, Scales.Value, 
Scales.ScaleID, RangeDef.Range;
```

Untested, but at minimum get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot! Unfortunately, that returns essentially the same results as the first query I posted, only without the few rows with the `null` values for Range that have 0 totals. This is very puzzling because my understanding of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is that it should return all rows from the table, but that isn't happening for me. It still skips the rows where there are no matches on Range. The cartesian join is the only one that seems to return the proper grouping so far, but yes, the totals are then off as a result.

Comment: I didn't realize the JOIN's after the LEFT OUTER JOIN would ruin that. I also realize that I didn't really answer what you wanted anyway. I'll set this up in sqlfiddle and see what I can figure out.